# How to force a picker to display an object after a data refresh

Tags: c#, xaml, picker

I have an Overview Page which hold multiple Flexlayout templates for different summaries for report territories.  I have a picker on the page that will filter the reports shown when the user selects a specific territory. The filtering for each territory or 'All Territories' works fine while on the overview page. The user can tap a report to see its details and navigates to the detail page. When the user navigates back to the overview page I refresh the entire set of data (a trip to the api & DB) and then refilter it based on the previous selection. This works fine. But the problem I am experiencing is that I cannot get the picker to display the previously selected territory. In the refresh of data I also refresh the list of territories. The picker's ItemSource & ItemDisplayBinding are set a  object. When the user selects a territory I set a global property (CurrTerritory) to the Picker's object (both are the same type). The picker's SelectedItem is bound to a property in then view model (SelectedItem). After the complete refresh of data I then set the vm.SelectedItem to the CurrTerritory object with the hopes the picker will display the previously selected territory, but it does not. So any help will be greatly appreciated.
The picker

```
                <Picker x:Name="territoryPicker" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Territories}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Territory}"
                Title="Choose a Territory"
                WidthRequest="275"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                FontSize="Small"                          
                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                SelectedIndexChanged="territoryPicker_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

Code Behind

```
        private void territoryPicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Territories _terr = territoryPicker.SelectedItem as Territories;

        if (_terr != null)
        {
            if (App.CurrTerritory.Territory != _terr.Territory)
            {
                App.CurrTerritory = _terr;
                if (App._AppStart) return;

                if (App.CurrTerritory.Territory.StartsWith( "All Territories") )
                {
                    overviewviewmodel.ResetFilter(App.ShowOnlyUserRequests);
                }
                else
                {
                    overviewviewmodel.Filter(App.CurrTerritory.Territory, App.ShowOnlyUserRequests);
                }
            }
            if(BindingContext == null)
                BindingContext = overviewviewmodel;
        }
    }
```

Viewmodel There is a lot here and I'm just showing the primary place where the SelectedItem is set. Before the CheckFilters method is called all of the data refresh has occurred.:

```
        static Territories _SelectedItem; 
    public Territories SelectedItem 
    {
        get { return _SelectedItem; } 
        set 
        { 
                _SelectedItem = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem"); 
        }
    }

        public void CheckFilters()
    {
        if (App.CurrTerritory != null && !App.CurrTerritory.Territory.StartsWith( "All Territories" ))
        {
            Filter(App.CurrTerritory.Territory.ToString(), App.ShowOnlyUserRequests);
            SelectedItem = App.CurrTerritory;
        }
        else
        {
            ResetFilter(App.ShowOnlyUserRequests);
            SelectedItem = App.CurrTerritory;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After much research on this I found that my issue boiled down to me assigning the App.CurrTerritory object to the SelectedItem object (SelectedItem = App.CurrTerritory;) after the refresh of data. The picker's ItemSource is a list of Territory objects and the SelectedItem obj is bound to the picker's SelectedItem property. Because I refreshed the list of territories with each refresh the App.CurrTerritory would no longer equal (==) any obj in the list even though the individual properties were equal. So in my foreach I compared the string property of CurrTerritory.Territory to each territory object in the list. When I found a match I reset the App.CurrTerriotry to the new obj found in the list and now I have an obj that does exist in the list. (FYI - _curr is the string value of the current App.CurrTerritory.Territory property)

```
            foreach (var territory in filteredTerritory) 
        {
            Territories.Add(territory);
            if(territory.Territory == _curr)
                _territory = territory;
        }
```

Refresh the global property App.Currterritory

```
            if(!App.CurrTerritory.Territory.StartsWith("All Territories"))
            App.CurrTerritory = _territory;
```

Now the assignment to the SelectedItem will have an obj in the list

```
                SelectedItem = App.CurrTerritory;
```

Hope this helps anyone stumbling onto this case